# Laptop plays music choppy after a few minutes of idling

Tags: hard-drive, memory, performance, windows-8.1, pagefile

I noticed that when I'm doing my homework and let my laptop play music, the music becomes choppy after 10-15 minutes. Like my laptop's freezing or something, but as soon as I do something (bring a program in background to front) is goes away.

I opened up resource monitor andit seems that when this happens the disc usage goed to about 8MB/s,and stays like it, but when I click anything it goed back to 0b/s and my computer works fine.

My laptop is a Windows 8.1 laptop, is there any way to avoid this? Should I Disable the page file? Maybe it's paging all my applications?

I have 8GB of memory and 1.5 GB in use so there is no way I'm running out of memory. An i7 processor (3rd generation) sits in my laptop and a powerfull NVidia GeForce graphics card so it's not my laptops performance issue..

Comment: Is your laptop going into some sort of power save mode? Try disabling that if it is.

Comment: My laptop is on highest performance settings, sleeping hibernation and all kind of that disabled, always plugged in

Comment: and I don't think that it's saving power when the disk usage goes up to 8MB/s from 0b/s :P

Comment: A likely cause is an application that begins some sort of scanning or indexing on your hard drive, like a virus scanner or a desktop search/indexing program. That's what I would be looking at first and foremost. Distributed computing programs could cause the same effect, but to a lesser extent.

Comment: hm I disabled in scheduled tasks a windows task which has a trigger "when pc is idle" and was named "optimize start menu cache" but it seems it wasn't that. got no antivirus running, firewalls disabled, windows defender removed, 1.5GB ram usage, all possible updates installed and a very fast system. From time to time I run a portable virus scanner, but I never download and install anything without testing it on my other computes so this is really strange, how could I pinpoint the program? Or maybe it's windows itself?

Comment: leave your task manager open when this happens, sorting it by disk usage. This should show you what process is using all the disk time